# Form not saving to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I made a form for a 5K run where the user enters basic information about him/her (first name, last name, email, organization, whether they are attending the event, and checking a checkbox after viewing a waiver form.

I placed a submit button at the end. I am having trouble connecting my form to my database. I already tried connecting and made a table in mySql called "basicInfo"  I am new to coding, so I appreciate all the help I can get and I am stuck on it.

This is my code so far

index.php (EDITED)

```
<?php


// Event name
$event = "2013 VIA-1 5K Run Fundraiser";

// Orgs  See table organisations
// $orgs = array('', 'Northeastern Illinois','Illinois Institute of Technology', 'Loyola', 'Oberlin', 'Northwestern', 'Purdue', 'IVSU', 'UW-Madison', 'UIllinois','Iowa State University', 'Michigan-Ann Arbor','Marquette University', 'Michigan State', 'UIC', 'Notre Dame', 'VSAM', 'Ohio State', 'UCincinnati', 'Northern Illinois', 'Indiana-Bloomington', 'University of Iowa', 'St. Cloud');
// asort($orgs);

// Registration fees for attendees and non-attendees
$fee_attendee = 10;
$fee_nonAttendee = 15;


$paypal_email = 'payment@example.com ';

// Registration closing date (will go until 11:59 PM Central Standard Time of this day)
$close_month = 03;
$close_day = 08;
$close_year = 2013;

// $time = time(); Easier to use the build in now function of MySQL. 


function clean($in)
{
    $out = trim(strip_tags($in));
    $out = addslashes($out);
    return $out;
}



function listform(){
$host = "local";
$user = "user";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";

// open connection to databse
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
        IF (!$link){
            echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
        }
        ELSE {
           //Get organisations from table organisations
           $query = "SELECT * FROM  organisations ORDER BY name ASC"; 
           $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
                    echo "<option value=".$row['id_organisations'].">".$row['name']."</option>\n";
                }
        }
        mysqli_close($link);
}

//Check if variables are post if so filter the input if not initiating variables for form
IF (isset($_POST['firstname'])){  
     $firstname  = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);    
}
ELSE {
    $firstname  = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['lastname'])){
            $lastname   = filter_var($_POST['lastname'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
}
ELSE {
    $lastname   = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['org'])){
   $org = $_POST['org'];
}
ELSE {
    $org    = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email  = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL),FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
ELSE {
    $email  = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['attendant'])){
    $attendant  = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['attendant'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
}
ELSE {
    $attendant  = "";
}
IF (isset($_POST['waiver'])){
    $waiver = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['waiver'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
}
ELSE {
    $waiver  = "";
}



function submit_form(){
    $host  = "host";
$user = "user";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";

    $firstname  = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $lastname   = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $org    = $_POST['org'];
    $email  = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL),FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $attendant  = $_POST['attendant'];

    // open connection to database
    $link = mysqli_connect($host,$user, $password, $database);
        IF (!$link){
            echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
        }
        ELSE {
           //INSERT VALUES INTO DATABASE
           $query = "INSERT INTO basicinfo (firstname,lastname,email,attendant,org,time) VALUES('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."', ".$attendant.", ".$org.", NOW())";
           return mysqli_query($link,$query);

        }
//close connection to database
        mysqli_close($link);

    }



//Warning messages initiation
$warning_firstname  = "*Required";
$warning_lastname   = "*Required";
$warning_org  = "*Required";
$warning_email   = "*Required";
$warning_attendant   = "*Required";
$warning_waiver      = "*Required";





$formfirstpart = <<<EODformfirspart
<HTML>
    <head><title>Form 5K RUN </title></head>
     <body style="background-color:gold">
     <tbody>
            <p>We're excited to introduce the 5K Run to VIA-1! During this year's conference, Individuals can register to participate in the fun across University of Iowa's campus in order to raise money for this year's CPP</p>
    <div class='row'>
        <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="POST" name="registration">
           <div class='column grid_5'>
            <label for='first'>First Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first" maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$firstname"><span class="warning">$warning_firstname</span><br><br>
            <label for='first'>Last Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id='lastname' maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$lastname" /><span class="warning">$warning_lastname</span><br /><br />
            <label for='email'>E-mail:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="email" id='email' maxlength="100" tabindex='3' VALUE="$email" /><span class="warning">$warning_email</span><br /><br />


           <label for="org">Organization:</label><br />
            <select id="org" name="org" tabindex="5" form="registration">

EODformfirspart;

$formlastpart = <<<EODlastpart
            </SELECT>
                <span class="warning">$warning_org</span><br /><br />

                    <label for='attendant'>Are you attending VIA-1?</label><br />

                <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-yes' value='1' /> <label for='attendant-yes'>Yes</label><br />
            <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-no' value='0' /> <label for='attendant-no'>No </label>$warning_attendant<br /><br />


            <input type='checkbox' class='radio' name='waiver' id='waiver' value=1  /> <label for='waiver'>I understand and agree to the terms of <a href='waiver.php' target="_blank">the waiver</a>.$warning_waiver</label>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <div class='column grid_10 right'>
            <input type="submit" class='button' name="submit" value="submit" tabindex='7' /></form>
        </div>

            </tbody>
        </div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>

EODlastpart;








IF(!IsSet($_POST['submit'])){ // Check if form is not send, if not display empty form.

echo $formfirstpart;
echo listform();
echo $formlastpart; 
}

ELSEIF (IsSet($_POST['submit']) AND (isset($firstname) OR isset($lastname) OR isset($email) OR  isset($org) OR isset($attendant))) {
$warning_counter = 0;
if ($firstname == "") {      
        $warning_firstname = 'Please provide your first name and / or a valid name';
                $warning_counter = + 1 ;
        }
if ($firstname == "") {      
        $warning_lastname = 'Please provide your last name and / or a valid name';
                $warning_counter = + 1;
        }
if ($email == "") {      
        $warning_email = 'Please provide your email adress and / or a valid email adress';
                $warning_counter = +1;
        }

if ($org == " ") {      
        $warning_org = 'Please select your organisation';
                $warning_counter = +1;
        }

if ($waiver == "") {      
        $warning_waiver = 'You have to accept the waiver agreement the otherwise you cannot attend'; 
                $warning_counter = +1;
        }
if ($attendant == "") {      
        $warning_attendant = 'Do you attend VIA-1?';
                $warning_counter =+1;
        } 
 if ($warning_counter>0){               
$formfirstpart1 = <<<EODformfirspart1
<HTML>
    <head><title>Form 5K RUN </title></head>
     <body style="background-color:gold">
     <tbody>
            <p>We're excited to introduce the 5K Run to VIA-1! During this year's conference, Individuals can register to participate in the fun across University of Iowa's campus in order to raise money for this year's CPP</p>
    <div class='row'>
        <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="POST" name="registration">
           <div class='column grid_5'>
            <label for='first'>First Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first" maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$firstname"><span class="warning">$warning_firstname</span><br><br>
            <label for='first'>Last Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id='lastname' maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$lastname" /><span class="warning">$warning_lastname</span><br /><br />
            <label for='email'>E-mail:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="email" id='email' maxlength="100" tabindex='3' VALUE="$email" /><span class="warning">$warning_email</span><br /><br />

        <label for="org">Organization:</label><br />
            <select id="org" name="org" tabindex="5" form="registration">


EODformfirspart1;



$formlastpart1 = <<<EODlastpart1
            </select>
                <span class="warning">$warning_org</span><br /><br />

                    <label for='attendant'>Are you attending VIA-1?</label><br />

                <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-yes' value='1' /> <label for='attendant-yes'>Yes</label><br />
            <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-no' value='0' /> <label for='attendant-no'>No </label><br />$warning_attendant<br />


            <input type='checkbox' class='radio' name='waiver' id='waiver' value=1  /> <label for='waiver'>I understand and agree to the terms of <a href='waiver.php' target="_blank">the waiver</a>.$warning_waiver</label>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <div class='column grid_10 right'>
            <input type="submit" class='button' name="submit" value="submit" tabindex='7' />
        </div>
        </form>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


    </font>
    </body>
    </html>



EODlastpart1;

    echo $formfirstpart1;
    echo listform();
    echo $formlastpart1;
 }
 IF ($warning_counter == 0){
submit_form();
header('Location: submitted.php');    
 }
}


?>
```

this is for the submitted.php (the next page)

```
<html>
    <head><title>Your form has been submitted</title></head>
    <body>
    <h1>See you at the 5K Run/walk for Memo.</h1>
    <p class="content">Your form has been submitted.</p>

    <p class="content">Click <a href="index.php">here</a> to go back to the main page.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you seem to be missing an SQL query, where you insert the data into your database, i gather that is what youre trying to do? If you do have that code and just left it out we will need to see it.

Comment: You do realize that your "clean" function doesn't actually prevent you from SQL injection attacks? See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for acceptable solutions. (And clean doesn't even seem to be used .. chalk another for placeholders.)

Comment: @Joe Doe- Isn't this it? if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO basicInfo VALUES('', '$_POST[first]', '$_POST[last]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[attendant]', '$org', $time, 0, '', 1)"))    What would be a good example of inserting data into the database? I thought the SQL "insert" command I put did it.

Comment: or is it wrong because I am inserting data into my table "basicInfo" and not the overall database "conference" ?

Comment: Have you included config.php into your index file? I do not see it.

Comment: Use MYSQLI_ instead of MYSQL_ for new code. From version 5.5 onwards MYSQL_ is depreciated.

Comment: @Ares I have not included. I put it in my header php file. Should I put " include("config.php"); " in it?

Comment: I would actually do require_once('config.php'); In order for your database functions to be available in your index file you need to include your config.php file. Otherwise you are trying to do a query without first connection to the database.

Comment: @pst $_POST is modified, the & in the foreach lets it iterate by value. Not a common method however.

Comment: @Thanks Ares!  However, I can't access my page now and i get this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end on line 120" It's referring to the "<? ?> at the end of my index.php file. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a basically two ways to use a form to send data to a database. First method is to let people fill out the form and send the data to an next page. You can add Java script to check if the filled out data meets your requirement and to imediatedly respond to . E.g. have all required field have been filled.  The next page progresses the data and send the data to the MySQL server. Form methods you could use are POST / GET. Second method is to display the form on one page and do the prossesing of the data on the same page (PHP_SELF or by referencing the same page in you form action). The second method requires that code is very structured. If you need to check if the data has been submitted. Next you need to verify is valid. If the form was submitted and the input valid the data is submitted to the database and the visitor is displayed a text like "Thank your for submitting your form . We will contact you as soon as possible.". If the form was submitted and the data was not valid the visitor should stay on the same page en get an error messages like "The following fields need to be fill out: ...." and the form should be displayed.  If the form was not submitted (on the first visit) the visitor should get the form displayed.

The most easy method to setup would be the first method the second is the nicest I think, but I suggest you start out with the first method. Once the first method is working you could add things like Javascript and / or change it to method two.

Try this:

```
<?php

// Event name
$event = "2013 VIA-1 5K Run Fundraiser";

// Orgs  See table organisations
// $orgs = array('', 'Northeastern Illinois','Illinois Institute of Technology', 'Loyola', 'Oberlin', 'Northwestern', 'Purdue', 'IVSU', 'UW-Madison', 'UIllinois','Iowa State University', 'Michigan-Ann Arbor','Marquette University', 'Michigan State', 'UIC', 'Notre Dame', 'VSAM', 'Ohio State', 'UCincinnati', 'Northern Illinois', 'Indiana-Bloomington', 'University of Iowa', 'St. Cloud');
// asort($orgs);

// Registration fees for attendees and non-attendees
$fee_attendee = 10;
$fee_nonAttendee = 15;


$paypal_email = 'payment@example.com ';

// Registration closing date (will go until 11:59 PM Central Standard Time of this day)
$close_month = 03;
$close_day = 08;
$close_year = 2013;

// $time = time(); Easier to use the build in now function of MySQL. 


function clean($in)
{
    $out = trim(strip_tags($in));
    $out = addslashes($out);
    return $out;
}



function listform(){
$host = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";

// open connection to databse
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
        IF (!$link){
            echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
        }
        ELSE {
           //Get organisations from table organisations
           $query = "SELECT * FROM  organisations ORDER BY name ASC"; 
           $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
                    echo "<option value=".$row['id_organisations'].">".$row['name']."</option>\n";
                }
        }
        mysqli_close($link);
}

//Check if variables are post if so filter the input if not initiating variables for form
IF (isset($_POST['firstname'])){  
     $firstname  = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);    
}
ELSE {
    $firstname  = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['lastname'])){
            $lastname   = filter_var($_POST['lastname'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
}
ELSE {
    $lastname   = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['org'])){
   $org = $_POST['org'];
}
ELSE {
    $org    = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email  = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL),FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
ELSE {
    $email  = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['attendant'])){
    $attendant  = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['attendant'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
}
ELSE {
    $attendant  = "";
}
IF (isset($_POST['waiver'])){
    $waiver = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['waiver'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
}
ELSE {
    $waiver  = "";
}



function submit_form(){
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "user";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "database";   

    $firstname  = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $lastname   = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $org    = $_POST['org'];
    $email  = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL),FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $attendant  = $_POST['attendant'];

    // open connection to database
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
        IF (!$link){
            echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
        }
        ELSE {
           //INSERT VALUES INTO DATABASE
           $query = "INSERT INTO basicInfo (firstname,lastname,email,attendant,org,time) VALUES('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."', ".$attendant.", ".$org.", NOW())";
           return mysqli_query($link,$query);

        }
//close connection to database
        mysqli_close($link);

    }



//Warning messages initiation
$warning_firstname  = "*Required";
$warning_lastname   = "*Required";
$warning_org  = "*Required";
$warning_email   = "*Required";
$warning_attendant   = "*Required";
$warning_waiver      = "*Required";





$formfirstpart = <<<EODformfirspart
<HTML>
    <head><title>Form 5K RUN </title></head>
     <body style="background-color:gold">
     <tbody>
            <p>We're excited to introduce the 5K Run to VIA-1! During this year's conference, Individuals can register to participate in the fun across University of Iowa's campus in order to raise money for this year's CPP</p>
    <div class='row'>
        <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="POST" name="registration">
           <div class='column grid_5'>
            <label for='first'>First Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first" maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$firstname"><span class="warning">$warning_firstname</span><br><br>
            <label for='first'>Last Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id='lastname' maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$lastname" /><span class="warning">$warning_lastname</span><br /><br />
            <label for='email'>E-mail:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="email" id='email' maxlength="100" tabindex='3' VALUE="$email" /><span class="warning">$warning_email</span><br /><br />

            <label for='org'>Organization:</label><br />
            <SELECT id="org" name="org">

EODformfirspart;

$formlastpart = <<<EODlastpart
            </SELECT>
                <span class="warning">$warning_org</span><br /><br />

                    <label for='attendant'>Are you attending VIA-1?</label><br />

                <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-yes' value='1' /> <label for='attendant-yes'>Yes</label><br />
            <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-no' value='0' /> <label for='attendant-no'>No </label>$warning_attendant<br /><br />


            <input type='checkbox' class='radio' name='waiver' id='waiver' value=1  /> <label for='waiver'>I understand and agree to the terms of <a href='waiver.php' target="_blank">the waiver</a>.$warning_waiver</label>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <div class='column grid_10 right'>
            <input type="submit" class='button' name="submit" value="submit" tabindex='7' /></form>
        </div>

            </tbody>
        </div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>

EODlastpart;









IF(!IsSet($_POST['submit'])){ // Check if form is not send, if not display empty form.

echo $formfirstpart;
echo listform();
echo $formlastpart; 
}

ELSEIF (IsSet($_POST['submit']) AND (isset($firstname) OR isset($lastname) OR isset($email) OR  isset($org) OR isset($attendant))) {
$warning_counter = 0;
if ($firstname == "") {      
        $warning_firstname = 'Please provide your first name and / or a valid name';
                $warning_counter = + 1 ;
        }
if ($firstname == "") {      
        $warning_lastname = 'Please provide your last name and / or a valid name';
                $warning_counter = + 1;
        }
if ($email == "") {      
        $warning_email = 'Please provide your email adress and / or a valid email adress';
                $warning_counter = +1;
        }

if ($org == " ") {      
        $warning_org = 'Please select your organisation';
                $warning_counter = +1;
        }

if ($waiver == "") {      
        $warning_waiver = 'You have to accept the waiver agreement the otherwise you cannot attend'; 
                $warning_counter = +1;
        }
if ($attendant == "") {      
        $warning_attendant = 'Do you attend VIA-1?';
                $warning_counter =+1;
        } 
 if ($warning_counter>0){               
$formfirstpart1 = <<<EODformfirspart1
<HTML>
    <head><title>Form 5K RUN </title></head>
     <body style="background-color:gold">
     <tbody>
            <p>We're excited to introduce the 5K Run to VIA-1! During this year's conference, Individuals can register to participate in the fun across University of Iowa's campus in order to raise money for this year's CPP</p>
    <div class='row'>
        <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="POST" name="registration">
           <div class='column grid_5'>
            <label for='first'>First Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first" maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$firstname"><span class="warning">$warning_firstname</span><br><br>
            <label for='first'>Last Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id='lastname' maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$lastname" /><span class="warning">$warning_lastname</span><br /><br />
            <label for='email'>E-mail:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="email" id='email' maxlength="100" tabindex='3' VALUE="$email" /><span class="warning">$warning_email</span><br /><br />

            <label for="org">Organization:</label><br />
            <select id="org" name="org" tabindex='5' form="registration">


EODformfirspart1;



$formlastpart1 = <<<EODlastpart1
            </select>
                <span class="warning">$warning_org</span><br /><br />

                    <label for='attendant'>Are you attending VIA-1?</label><br />

                <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-yes' value='1' /> <label for='attendant-yes'>Yes</label><br />
            <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-no' value='0' /> <label for='attendant-no'>No </label><br />$warning_attendant<br />


            <input type='checkbox' class='radio' name='waiver' id='waiver' value=1  /> <label for='waiver'>I understand and agree to the terms of <a href='waiver.php' target="_blank">the waiver</a>.$warning_waiver</label>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <div class='column grid_10 right'>
            <input type="submit" class='button' name="submit" value="submit" tabindex='7' />
        </div>
        </form>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


    </font>
    </body>
    </html>

EODlastpart1;

    echo $formfirstpart1;
    echo listform();
    echo $formlastpart1;
 }
 IF ($warning_counter == 0){
submit_form();
header('Location: submitted.php');    
 }
}


?>
```

After you have completed the form you will be redirect to this page submitted.php

```
<html>
    <head><title>Your form has been submitted</title></head>
    <body>
    <h1>See you at the 5K run.</h1>
    <p class="content">Your form has been submitted. Good luck with your training workouts</p>

    <p class="content">Click <a href="index.php">here</a> to go back to the main page.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS organisations (
  id_organisations int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_organisations)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS basicinfo (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  firstname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  org int(11) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  attendant int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23f3b/4)

Important to note this is just a start. I haven't tested it so bear that in mind. I didn't understand some part of your code so I had to do some guess work.

EDIT: Removal of old database and import of structure and data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS basicinfo;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS organisations;


CREATE TABLE organisations (
      id_organisations int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id_organisations)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE basicinfo (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  firstname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  org int(11) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  attendant int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `organisations` (`id_organisations`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Northeastern Illinois'),
(2, 'Illinois Institute of Technology'),
(3, 'Loyola'),
(4, 'Oberlin'),
(5, 'Northwestern'),
(6, 'Purdue'),
(7, 'IVSU'),
(8, 'UW-Madison'),
(9, 'UIllinois'),
(10, 'Iowa State University'),
(11, 'Michigan-Ann Arbor'),
(12, 'Marquette University'),
(13, 'Michigan State'),
(14, 'UIC'),
(15, 'Notre Dame'),
(16, 'VSAM'),
(17, 'Ohio State'),
(18, 'UCincinnati'),
(19, 'Northern Illinois'),
(20, 'Indiana-Bloomington'),
(21, 'University of Iowa'),
(22, 'St. Cloud');
```

Change UID into ID in the PHP code if your have changed it before. The above query will delete your table (basicinfo) and then recreate two new tables (basicinfo and organisations). This how you would apply it to your own database. Copy the SQL code above to phpmyadmin. Login into phpmyadmin -> select your database -> SQL -> Remove the default text and copy the code above into the window -> run the query (start).

If want to just alter your database you could use this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `basicinfo` 
CHANGE `uid` `id` INT auto_increment,
CHANGE `firstname` `firstname` varchar(30),
CHANGE `lastname` `lastname` varchar(50),
CHANGE `org` `org` INT,
CHANGE `email` `email` VARCHAR(100), 
ADD `time` datetime NOT NULL;
```

But you still need to create and populate the organisation database.

```
CREATE TABLE organisations (
      id_organisations int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id_organisations)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `organisations` (`id_organisations`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Northeastern Illinois'),
(2, 'Illinois Institute of Technology'),
(3, 'Loyola'),
(4, 'Oberlin'),
(5, 'Northwestern'),
(6, 'Purdue'),
(7, 'IVSU'),
(8, 'UW-Madison'),
(9, 'UIllinois'),
(10, 'Iowa State University'),
(11, 'Michigan-Ann Arbor'),
(12, 'Marquette University'),
(13, 'Michigan State'),
(14, 'UIC'),
(15, 'Notre Dame'),
(16, 'VSAM'),
(17, 'Ohio State'),
(18, 'UCincinnati'),
(19, 'Northern Illinois'),
(20, 'Indiana-Bloomington'),
(21, 'University of Iowa'),
(22, 'St. Cloud');
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e616c/1)

**FINAL EDIT**:

```
<?php


// Event name
$event = "2013 VIA-1 5K Run Fundraiser";

// Registration fees for attendees and non-attendees
$fee_attendee = 10;
$fee_nonAttendee = 15;


$paypal_email = 'payment@example.com ';

// Registration closing date (will go until 11:59 PM Central Standard Time of this day)
$close_month = 03;
$close_day = 08;
$close_year = 2013;

// $time = time(); Easier to use the build in now function of MySQL. 


function clean($in)
{
    $out = trim(strip_tags($in));
    $out = addslashes($out);
    return $out;
}



function listform(){
$host = "host";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "databasename";

// open connection to databse
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
        IF (!$link){
            echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
        }
        ELSE {
           //Get organisations from table organisations
           $query = "SELECT * FROM  organisations ORDER BY name ASC"; 
           $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
                    echo "<option value=".$row['id_organisations'].">".$row['name']."</option>\n";
                }
        }
        mysqli_close($link);
}

//Check if variables are post if so filter the input if not initiating variables for form
IF (isset($_POST['firstname'])){  
     $firstname  = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);    
}
ELSE {
    $firstname  = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['lastname'])){
            $lastname   = filter_var($_POST['lastname'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
}
ELSE {
    $lastname   = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['org'])){
   $org = $_POST['org'];
}
ELSE {
    $org    = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email  = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL),FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
ELSE {
    $email  = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['attendant'])){
    $attendant  = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['attendant'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
}
ELSE {
    $attendant  = "";
}
IF (isset($_POST['waiver'])){
    $waiver = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['waiver'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
}
ELSE {
    $waiver  = "";
}



function submit_form(){
    $host  = "host";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "databasename";

    $firstname  = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $lastname   = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $org    = $_POST['org'];
    $email  = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL),FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $attendant  = $_POST['attendant'];

    // open connection to database
    $link = mysqli_connect($host,$user, $password, $database);
        IF (!$link){
            echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
        }
        ELSE {
           //INSERT VALUES INTO DATABASE
           $query = "INSERT INTO basicinfo (firstname,lastname,email,attendant,org,time) VALUES('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."', ".$attendant.", ".$org.", NOW())";
           return mysqli_query($link,$query);

        }
//close connection to database
        mysqli_close($link);

    }



//Warning messages initiation
$warning_firstname  = "*Required";
$warning_lastname   = "*Required";
$warning_org  = "*Required";
$warning_email   = "*Required";
$warning_attendant   = "*Required";
$warning_waiver      = "*Required";





$formfirstpart = <<<EODformfirspart
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form 5K RUN </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

    </head>
    <body style="background-color:gold">

            <div>We're excited to introduce the 5K Run to VIA-1! During this year's conference, Individuals can register to participate in the fun across University of Iowa's campus in order to raise money for this year's CPP</div>
    <div class="row">
        <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="POST" name="registration">
           <div class="column grid_5">
               <label for='first'>First Name:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first" maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$firstname" /><span class="warning">$warning_firstname</span></br></br>
            <label for='first'>Last Name:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id='lastname' maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$lastname" /><span class="warning">$warning_lastname</span></br></br>
            <label for='email'>E-mail:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="email" id='email' maxlength="100" tabindex='3' VALUE="$email" /><span class="warning">$warning_email</span></br></br>


           <label for="org">Organization:</label><br />
            <select id="org" name="org" tabindex="5">

EODformfirspart;

$formlastpart = <<<EODlastpart
                            </select>
                <span class="warning">$warning_org</span><br /><br />

                    <label for='attendant'>Are you attending VIA-1?</label><br />

                <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-yes' value='1' /> <label for='attendant-yes'>Yes</label><br />
            <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-no' value='0' /> <label for='attendant-no'>No </label><br />$warning_attendant<br />


            <input type='checkbox' class="radio" name="waiver" id="waiver" value="1"  /> <label for='waiver'>I understand and agree to the terms of <a href='waiver.php' target="_blank">the waiver</a>.$warning_waiver</label>
        </div>

    <div class='column grid_10 right'>
            <input type="submit" class='button' name="submit" value="submit" tabindex='7' />
            </form>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
EODlastpart;








IF(!IsSet($_POST['submit'])){ // Check if form is not send, if not display empty form.

echo $formfirstpart;
echo listform();
echo $formlastpart; 
}

ELSEIF (IsSet($_POST['submit']) AND (isset($firstname) OR isset($lastname) OR isset($email) OR  isset($org) OR isset($attendant))) {
$warning_counter = 0;
if ($firstname == "") {      
        $warning_firstname = 'Please provide your first name and / or a valid name';
                $warning_counter = + 1 ;
        }
if ($firstname == "") {      
        $warning_lastname = 'Please provide your last name and / or a valid name';
                $warning_counter = + 1;
        }
if ($email == "") {      
        $warning_email = 'Please provide your email adress and / or a valid email adress';
                $warning_counter = +1;
        }

if ($org == " ") {      
        $warning_org = 'Please select your organisation';
                $warning_counter = +1;
        }

if ($waiver == "") {      
        $warning_waiver = 'You have to accept the waiver agreement the otherwise you cannot attend'; 
                $warning_counter = +1;
        }
if ($attendant == "") {      
        $warning_attendant = 'Do you attend VIA-1?';
                $warning_counter =+1;
        } 
 if ($warning_counter>0){               
$formfirstpart1 = <<<EODformfirspart1
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form 5K RUN </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

    </head>
    <body style="background-color:gold">

            <div>We're excited to introduce the 5K Run to VIA-1! During this year's conference, Individuals can register to participate in the fun across University of Iowa's campus in order to raise money for this year's CPP</div>
    <div class="row">
        <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="POST" name="registration">
           <div class="column grid_5">
               <label for='first'>First Name:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first" maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$firstname" /><span class="warning">$warning_firstname</span></br></br>
            <label for='first'>Last Name:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id='lastname' maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$lastname" /><span class="warning">$warning_lastname</span></br></br>
            <label for='email'>E-mail:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="email" id='email' maxlength="100" tabindex='3' VALUE="$email" /><span class="warning">$warning_email</span></br></br>


           <label for="org">Organization:</label><br />
            <select id="org" name="org" tabindex="5">


EODformfirspart1;



$formlastpart1 = <<<EODlastpart1

                            </select>
                <span class="warning">$warning_org</span><br /><br />

                    <label for='attendant'>Are you attending VIA-1?</label><br />

                <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-yes' value='1' /> <label for='attendant-yes'>Yes</label><br />
            <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-no' value='0' /> <label for='attendant-no'>No </label><br />$warning_attendant<br />


            <input type='checkbox' class="radio" name="waiver" id="waiver" value="1"  /> <label for='waiver'>I understand and agree to the terms of <a href='waiver.php' target="_blank">the waiver</a>.$warning_waiver</label>
        </div>

    <div class='column grid_10 right'>
            <input type="submit" class='button' name="submit" value="submit" tabindex='7' />
            </form>
</div>
    </body>
</html>



EODlastpart1;

    echo $formfirstpart1;
    echo listform();
    echo $formlastpart1;
 }
 IF ($warning_counter == 0){
submit_form();
header('Location: submitted.php');    
 }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, though I generally loathe these suggestions, have you considered using a google doc with a form front end? They're a super easy way for non-developers to get data from people, and have it arrive in a spreadsheet.

Baring that, I'm assuming you're using an auto-increment primary key, might I suggest changing your query to:

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO basicInfo VALUES(null, '{$_POST['first]}', '{$_POST['last']}', '{$_POST['email']}', '{$_POST['attendant']}', '$org', $time, 0, '', 1)"))
    {
```

I've changed your '' to a null, as you want the DB to insert what it wants there. I've also changed the way you're including associative arrays in the string to a way that generally makes PHP happier.

For cleaning the $_POST array, something like

```
$expected = array('first', 'last', 'expected', 'attendant');
foreach($expected as $k)
{
  $p[$k] = clean($_POST[$k]);
}
//then changing the query to use $p rather than $_POST, clearly.
```

past that, as others have suggested, I would strongly recommend you use `mysql_real_escape_string()` rather than some sort of addslashes() combo.

Posting the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE basicInfo;` or any errors will help with MySQL issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made that change to my query! I had considered a google doc, but there's stuff regarding paypal that i need to add later for a payment option, so I prefer to do it this way even though I think Google docs would be great.

Comment: I can't access my page now and i get this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end on line 120" It's referring to the "<? ?> at the end of my index.php file. What could be wrong?

Comment: I found that when I insert <?
if(isset($_POST['reg']))
    {

        foreach($_POST AS &$p)
            $p = clean($p);

        $org = ($_POST['org'] == 'Other') ? $_POST['otherorg'] : $_POST['org'];




        if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO basicInfo VALUES(null, '{$_POST['first']}', '{$_POST['last']}', '{$_POST['email']}', '{$_POST['attendant']}', '$org', $time, 0, '', 1)"))
    {
            $uid = mysql_insert_id();
?>    my page doesn't generate, but when I delete that whole block of code, my page shows up.

Comment: @Mr. Radical I've tried adding a "}" at various points in index.php but can't seem to figure it out. Do you know where it could be missing?

Comment: @DigitalWoman I see an opening bracket before $uid it must close somewhere.